# How to use bigserial for primary key id with Sails js

Tags: sails.js, sails-postgresql

I have the following model definition:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    id: {
    type: 'bigserial',
    primaryKey: true
  },
  email: {
    type: 'email',
    required: true,
    unique: true
  }
}
```

When I lifed sails, it didn't give me warning about "bigserial" data type, even though it is not officially documented.

However, on the table created on Postgresql, the column "id" has a type "text". How do I have bigserial primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this command in your DB `ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN key_column BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY;

In Sails model you can use somethin like this:

```
 module.exports = {
  connection: yourConnection,
  tableName: yourTableName,
  attributes: {
    id: {
    type: 'integer',
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  email: {
    type: 'email',
    required: true,
    unique: true
  }
}
```

Note: you need to set your db connection config previously on `config/connections.js`

```
  somePostgresqlServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
    host: 'YOUR_POSTGRES_SERVER_HOSTNAME_OR_IP_ADDRESS',
    user: 'YOUR_POSTGRES_USER',
    password: 'YOUR_POSTGRES_PASSWORD',
    database: 'YOUR_POSTGRES_DB'
  }
```

and run `npm install sails-postgresql`in your project folder